# Dotnet CLI fails building after mv to other directory?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

Currently, I'm doing my second day of my first internship at a smaller company where I have to build something in C#. Except from Unity, I've never used C# before so I'm kinda new in using it. I'm currently using it on Linux Ubuntu 20. So forgive me for this most likely beginner question.

I'm using dotnet-sdk to build calling "dotnet clean; dotnet build; dotnet ~/pathToDLL/etc/etc". I've finally got something working now, So I cloned the empty git repository from the company and used the mv command to move my directory with some working code to the git repo. Now, when I try to build it it gives the following errors:

> /snap/dotnet-sdk/107/sdk/5.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5):
> error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/home/oscar/
> Tacho/card_reader/obj/project.assets.json' not found.
> Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
> [/home/oscar/Tacho/card_reader/card_reader.csproj]

It gives more or less the same error twice.

> /snap/dotnet-sdk/107/sdk/5.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5):
> error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/home/oscar/
> Tacho/card_reader/obj/project.assets.json' not found.
> Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
> [/home/oscar/Tacho/card_reader/card_reader.csproj]

For most users reading this error, this is probably an easy fix. But as I said, I've zero experience using C# on Linux (or Windows) outside of the context of Unity. So any explanation and fix will be very much appreciated!

Oscar

### solved

There was a space somewhere in the directory I copied my working code to. I removed this space (and everything before it) for this question because there was company sensitive information there which my boss didn't want to see end up on the internet. Because of the space (in the git repo name) Linux obviously had errors executing commands. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: Which command is giving that error? Are you able to provide a [mcve]? If you *just* clone then build, without renaming the directory, does that work?

Comment: I've tried them seperately and found out that the 'dotnet build' command gives the error. The git repo was completely empty, I just moved my directory there with my code. When i move my directory back to the original location in the filesystem everything works again. So it has something to do with the path setting in some project files i quess.

Comment: Open the csproj file with notepad and check path properties.  It is easier to locate issues with using Notepad than to try to find issue looking and the nest properties in VS,

Comment: @jdweng: Opening a project file for a .NET Core SDK-style project in Visual Studio shows the project file contents directly. So unless this is genuinely an "old style" project, there's no need to go for notepad.

Comment: I would suggest that after moving the directory, you remove the obj and bin directories. (While `dotnet clean` *may* do this, I generally find it simpler to just remove the directories directly.) Then do a `dotnet build` and see if the problem persists. If it does, please try to provide a [mcve] so we can help you more - otherwise I can see us just going back and forth for ages.

Comment: Fixed it. going to type the solution now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate that a NuGet package is missing some files. NuGet is a popular library distribution system that is also built into Visual Studio. Even an empty repository may be referencing the package as a dependency or your own code may be using that it. If you are using Visual Studio you can do the following:

1. Enable package restore by choosing Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager. Under Package Restore options, select Allow NuGet to download missing packages.
2. In Solution Explorer, right click the solution and select Restore NuGet Packages.

Your company might be using a private NuGet server though, so  you will want to make sure you are connected to any VPN services. Also do not be shy about asking a co-worker about this issue. This is likely part of configuring your environment properly and not something you are expected to 'just know' as a new intern.